# "pin visual" missing in Power BI web reading mode

Tags: powerbi

When I open a report in power BI web application, I'd like to pin visuals to dashboard, but the pin visual functionality is missing. I don't want to go to edit mode i want to give the admin user access to drag and drop any one of the visual from one dashboard and other visual from different dashboard, and place all in one dashboard.

Can I activate it somehow?

i have uploaded my report in powerbi server and tried to get the pin option in reading view but pin visual is available in edit mode only.
[image: pin visual in edit mode]

[image: in reading mode that option is not coming]